WunderTrading comment in Strategy.close line
Strategy is connected to WunderTrading using an alert on trading view.
The strategy is entering but not exiting trades. Can someone look at my strategy.close line and tell me if the comment from the WunderTrading platform is in the correct place?
strategy.close(id="RSIDivLE", comment="EXIT-LONG_MEXC_BTCUSDC_original_1M_ee83373a1e409343"+tostring(close - strategy.position_avg_price, "####.##"), when= abs(strategy.position_size)>=1  and  sl_type == "NONE" and longCloseCondition)

I have tried putting it in a couple of different spots in that line and there are no error messages when saving the script. The exit alerts are triggering correctly on trading view, but not registering on WunderTrading.

v4? We recommend the latest version: v5

Can you add an alert message you received with this command?
